# When texture quality is reduced, how is it actually reduced?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm no gamer, so excuse my ignorance (you can see that from my other SE accounts :P)

Just played Skyrim over a few weeks, and have been more obsessed on the tweaks than the game itself (It's a freakingly customizable game!). I just run a "craptop" on i5-3337U, 4GB RAM. Done a few tweaks here and there and managed ~30FPS *with textures setting still set at "Very High"*.

**What does the game actually do when I change the texture quality via the launcher/configurator?**

- Does the game already come with pre-sized textures for each texture level and use them accordingly? Like if I set it to low, it loads all textures from the "low category"?
- Or does it down-scale on-the-fly the hi-res textures the game comes with?

  - And if it does do that down-scaling on-the-fly, isn't that a performance hit?

Comment: Is this specifically about how Skyrim handles its graphics rendering?  Or games in general?  We might be able to handle a question about Skyrim, but a general one might be a bit too broad.

Comment: @Frank I'll limit this to just Skyrim. Just thought about that after posting the question.

Comment: The lower the texture quality, the lower the resolution the texture, therefore less data has to be streamed, computed and displayed. As well as less memory used on the gpu

Comment: @eyeofthehawks The question was more of *how the game does low-res textures*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skyrim comes with what you term low res textures, indeed the "high resolution HD texture pack" was released post general release. Seemingly as with other Bethesda games if the system and the system resources are struggling, the game will load the respective lower texture pack if it needs to, there should be no scaling on the fly, as you say.

Since you have selected the "very high" resolution texture pack and are still getting an at least playable, FPS I wouldn't worry too much.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the game already come with pre-sized textures for each texture
>   level and use them accordingly? Like if I set it to low, it loads all
>   textures from the "low category"?

Yes, and Yes.

> Or does it down-scale on-the-fly the hi-res textures the game comes
>   with?

No.

> And if it does do that down-scaling on-the-fly

It doesn't.

> isn't that a performance hit?

Yes, it would be if it did. But the performance hit would be far less than it would be if your GPU was constantly swapping textures in an out because there wasn't enough VRAM to load the high res textures.